# How to determine the lattice vector direction and magnitude in ASE

Tags: python, atomic-simulation-environment, materials-design

I am using the ASE library to compute the distance matrix with minimum image convention. In that, I have got the positions of all atoms in the cell.

Now I wish to calculate the distance between each of them by considering the translation vector on the three Bravais lattice vectors. For example the position of atom is `pos1 = [0.11 , 0.23 , 0.156]` now I have to translate this using the combinations of the three lattice vectors `(t1,t2,t3)` with cell size `(a,b,c)` respectively. That will be, like

```
pos1_1 = [0.11+a*t1 , 0.23 , 0.156]
pos1_2 =...
```

And so on.

How can this be done with ASE?

Comment: How does what you are looking to do differ from the `get_distance()`, `get_distances()`, and `get_all_distances()` methods of `ase.Atoms` ? All of those allow a bool flag for the use of MIC as input.

Comment: Actually, I wish to not use the existing library functions and develop my own function for my understanding. I tried looking up the source code, but I couldn't relate it with my code.

Comment: @AndreyPoletayev , how to use get_all_distances() with only data of positions of atoms, cell length and cell angles?

Comment: What you have is enough information to construct an `ase.Atoms` object. Then calling its `get_all_distances()` returns the full all-to-all distances matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offsets in positions is straightforwardly done in ASE:

```py
# just a test system
from ase.build import bulk
ni = bulk('Ni', 'hcp', a=2.5, c=4.0)

# now to process for an offset
t1 = 1
t2 = 2
t3 = 3
print("cell = ")
print(ni.cell)
print("before translation = ")
print(ni.positions)
ni.positions += (t1, t2, t3) @ ni.cell
print("after translation = ")
print(ni.positions)
```

However, I think you should look into https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/neighborlist.html for details on getting actual neighbours in a faster fashion :)

Comment: Also can you suggest on how to compute the lattice vectors; given the information about unit cell edge length = [a,b,c] and the dihededral angles (in degrees) = [ alpha, beta,gamma].

Comment: But actually, I only wish to know the directions of the unit cell. I will calculate the new positions myself. So, the [t1,t2,t3] unit vectors of the cell are required.

Comment: Hey, btw I don't know about the structure  'hcp' , how to use this?

Comment: As for length + angles, see this method: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/cell.html#ase.cell.Cell.new. Search the documentation for hcp, and it should come